# Downgrade facebook API?

Tags: facebook, hwioauthbundle

I am using facebook API to login by OAuth

However from V2.4 'email' is not available from facebook.
My System is made by [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md)

HWIOAuthBundle does not support the 2.4 yet.

Then I would like to downgrade the API version,
but I can't figure out how to do it.

facebook developpers -> My Apps  shows 'API Version v2.4.'

Is there any solution?

Comment: Your app can only use the lowest API version that was already announced when your app was created. So if your app was created after v2.4 was introduced, then you can not “downgrade” to any API version lower than that. You would have to find an “older” app, that was created before that already. (But if you already have an active user base, then switching app ids now would perhaps not be a good idea either. Keep in mind, that user ids are app-scoped now, so you would get different user id if you switched out apps now.)

Comment: _“However from V2.4 'email' is not available from facebook’_ – the field is still available, it just needs to be explicitly asked for now. So where in previous API versions a request for `/me` would return all the user profile info the app has access to, now that request would need to be `/me?fields=email,…` – and that is the point where HWIOAuthBundle would need to change their code (if the actual API request being made is not exposed to you.)

Comment: I see thanks @CBroe. I understood though I need to wait the library update.